# Which type of list is this and how can I access tokenValue?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, jwt

I have to implement an OAuth Client and am struggling a little bit with accessing the JWT-token for further requests to the OAuth Server.

I've already found it inside the debugger (it's somewhere inside the variable `principal`, which is accessible - I need to access `principal`→ `idToken`→ `tokenValue`), but I don't know which type of list this is and how I can store its content inside a variable?

The confusing part is, that `principal` has some content (`String`), too. But it also seems to be some kind of list, which can be extended and there are further elements indexed by `String`s.

The function, I am trying to access the token (the commented line at the end didn't work):

```java
// calling Google Calendar API
@GetMapping("/api_request")
public Map<String, Object> getCalendars(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
    // JWT is saved as String in principal→idToken→tokenValue
    String uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return Collections.singletonMap("response",restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class));
    //  return Collections.singletonMap("principal",principal.getAttribute("idToken"));
}
```

Here you can see the structure inside the debugger:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the question is a little bit confusing but I will try to answer.

First, you have method return type Map<String, Object>, a map is a collection interface, that has multiple implementations, more on map here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Second, since you have a method return type as map, you are logically returning a map, return Collections.singletonMap(key, val) and in your case it is a map with one entry having "response" as a key and whatever string response is returned form rest call: restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class).

Third, your principal has a DefaultOidcUser implementation class, that has methods to get the principal token, like: public OidcIdToken getIdToken(), more info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/oidc/user/DefaultOidcUser.html

Hopefully, this clears some thing out,
Cheers.